# Xcode 6.4 not going to accurate line of Crash

Tags: ios6, crash, xcode6

My application is crashing sometimes while running on real device but the debugger always goes to "main.m" class not where the app is exactly crashing.

Infect console log is also not telling anything about the crash.

I think there is some settings required for debugger but not exactly know the right solution for that. Please help.

Comment: Did you open the Devices Window in Xcode and check the hardware device log as noted?

Answer (score 0):

Check your device logs for an app type of Unknown. Often, an app will crash by being killed by the OS and an unknown log entry will appear on your device logs showing that your app is the largest memory consumer. To figure out which piece of code is causing the crash, evaluate the UI behavior and add a breakpoint at the appropriate spot (probably where you start working with your data).

Answer (score 0):

Perphaps this could be a memory issue. In that case debugger does not show warning or exceptions. you can use instruments like profile provided in xcode to backtrace the issue. You can also backtrace your issue in Report navigator in xcode.

You can also use apps like crashlytics. Upload your build to crashlytics and then download it from theer and use it. Once it gets crashed .Login on web and check for the crashes. It will show the exact line where got gets crashed.

I hope it can help you.